# AttributeError: module 'matplotlib.pyplot' has no attribute 'axline'

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a problem :

Here is the documentation : https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/pyplots/axline.html#sphx-glr-gallery-pyplots-axline-py

Here is my code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

for pos in np.linspace(-2, 1, 10):
    plt.axline((pos, 0), slope=0.5, color='k', transform=plt.gca().transAxes)

plt.ylim([0, 1])
plt.xlim([0, 1])
plt.show()
```

Here is the terminal :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/toto/path/of/the/project/testsubplot.py", line 7, in <module>
    plt.axline((pos, 0), slope=0.5, color='k', transform=plt.gca().transAxes)
AttributeError: module 'matplotlib.pyplot' has no attribute 'axline'
```

I am on Ubuntu 20.1 and I have matplotlib-3.5.1.

Why do I have this error ? I really don't understand why I have `AttributeError: module 'matplotlib.pyplot' has no attribute 'axline'`. In fact It has the attribute, so why do I have this error ? And how can I fix it ?

Comment: Try deleting and reinstalling the package. I have the same version and your code works.

Comment: Print matplotlib.__version__ pretty sure it is not 3.5

Comment: @JafarIsbarov Thank you it works ! It's a problem of environment !

Comment: Glad to hear that. I deleted my answer, because it was wrong.

Comment: I have the same problem with Google Colab

Answer (score 3):

!pip install matplotlib --upgrade
in google colab this works for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I tried [AdriQu3](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2981685/adriqu3)'s solution (in CoLab) but got another error because of some dependecies.
Solved adding 
`!pip install imgaug==0.2.5`
before
`!pip install matplotlib --upgrade`