# (seaborn)AttributeError:'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'axline'

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

My goal is to draw axline at each facet. But the "AttributeError:'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'axline'' shows, which I don't know why. How to modify code below?

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data = pd.DataFrame({'site':['a','a','b','b'], 'val':[0.1,0.2,0.3,0.2],
                    'X1':['c','d','c','d'],'X3':['e','e','f','f']})
g = sns.FacetGrid(data, row="site", col="X1", margin_titles=True, height=2.5)
g.map(plt.scatter, "X3", "val", color="#338844", edgecolor="white", s=50, lw=1)
for ax in g.axes_dict.values():
      ax.axline((0, 0), slope=.2, c=".2", ls="--", zorder=0)
```

Comment: It was displayed correctly in my environment (seaborn:0.12.1,matplotlib:3.6.0). i saw a graph with right ascending dashed lines on the 4 subplots.

Comment: my environment: seaborn 0.11.2.matplotlib 3.1.1. It seems that the version is out of date.thank you for your reply

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70714720/attributeerror-module-matplotlib-pyplot-has-no-attribute-axline